# Why does not identity theorem works for Quaternions, Octonions, Sedenions etc?

Tags: complex-analysis, quaternions, hypercomplex-numbers

Big chunk of complex analysis is built around the  [**Identity theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)
which in layman terms "allows analytical continuation to happen". Is there more or less intuitive way to understand why does it breaks (or at least some weaker lemmas) for higher spaces?

Comment: What source is telling you it "breaks"?  And where have you been reading about results on power series to define functions on those larger spaces, e.g., what do you even *mean* by powers when multiplication is no longer associative?

Comment: [For starters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_analysis), quaternions don't equate analytic, conformal, harmonic and holomorphic functions. That shouldn't be surprising. Since quaternions don't commute, defining derivatives requires unusual care, and can't be path-independent if you want, for example, $q^2$ to be differentiable. So *if* the identity theorem fails in quaternionic analysis (I haven't found sources either way on this), it could just be because the analysis as a whole is very different. After all, *real* analysis doesn't have all the nice properties of complex analysis.

Comment: @KCd Well, all the mentioned algebras are still power-associative.

Comment: @KCd Series is only one of many interpretation to define a function in some open set D. One can define a few functions w/o using series, and let's say 
two functions that are similar enough (equal on some well defined in identity theorem subset of D) _could_ be equal in whole open set D. But they aren't.

Comment: That's true, VP, but from the Wikipedia article on the Identity theorem you cite: "The underpinning fact from which the theorem is established is the expandability of a holomorphic function into its Taylor series." So there shouldn't be any surprise here.

Comment: The subject itself is interesting but the question's title is badly written. It is partly a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622895/is-there-much-theory-developed-for-analytic-functions-of-quaternions-or-of-octon) except for sedenions.